# Why does all of my internet traffic go through one interface?

Tags: networking, ip

Why does all of my internet traffic go through one interface?
I have three interfaces that have their own public IP address on my server.

For example, when I ping the IP of venet0:3 then I see zero traffic on it and I see traffic usage on venet0 of which I am 100% sure it's from that ping.

This is my `/etc/network/interfaces`: (I never touched the file)

```
# Auto generated lo interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Auto generated venet0 interface
auto venet0
iface venet0 inet manual
        up ifconfig venet0 up
        up ifconfig venet0 127.0.0.2
        up route add default dev venet0
        down route del default dev venet0
        down ifconfig venet0 down


iface venet0 inet6 manual
        up ifconfig venet0 add 2a06:1c40::3bf/128
        down ifconfig venet0 del 2a06:1c40::3bf/128
        up route -A inet6 add default dev venet0
        down route -A inet6 del default dev venet0

auto venet0:0
iface venet0:0 inet static
        address 37.228.134.142
        netmask 255.255.255.255

auto venet0:2
iface venet0:2 inet static
        address 37.228.134.183
        netmask 255.255.255.255

auto venet0:3
iface venet0:3 inet static
        address 185.101.92.16
        netmask 255.255.255.255
```

As requested, `route-n`

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 venet0
```

And `ip route`

```
default dev venet0  scope link
```

What I'm trying to do is that traffic from `37.228.134.142` goes through `venet:0`, `37.228.134.183` goes through `venet0:2` and `185.101.92.16` goes through `venet0:3`.

Comment: Why downvoting this? Sounds like a good question to me...

Comment: You might want to post the output for `route -n` for us to see how traffics are passed. And if I guess it right, your `vnet0` is pretty much the default interface. You will need routing placed depending on your requirement.

Comment: @AzkerM I've added the information requested to the question.

Comment: I'm totally confused right now. You don't have routing at all. All what it says is, whatever the traffic, that should be passed through `vnet:0` What is this server? what are you exactly trying to do? When you say; **What I'm trying to do is that traffic from 37.228.134.142 goes through venet:0** so and so forth, what traffic? from where? You need to be more descriptive for us to breakdown and assist you further.

Comment: @AzkerM I'll explain. I was looking through the adapters to see how much traffic some gameservers/webservers use. What I didn't understand is that all adapters had an usage of zero. Nothing. Except venet0. That one had constant high usage. I don't know how to explain it. But I'll try. What I am trying to do here is that traffic going to the adapters IP goes through that adapter and not all through venet0.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you are following my query. What I meant was, those public IPs are configured to a server/gateway... etc? Who and how it is been accessed.. may be a diagram will help!

Comment: @AzkerM I rent a VPS (OpenVZ) at a hosting. Those IP addresses come with it. I've binded some servers to a specific IP. My point is that for some reason all of the traffic goes through one adapter. Regardless of the IP I bind. So I need help with setting up the routes so that a gameserver's traffic that's bound to the IP of venet0:3, shows that it goes through that adapter. (I'm using slurm to track the usage of the adapters, and on all of them but venet0 it's showing nothing all the time). If you need to know anything specific, let me know. I'm bad in explaining in general, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of "packet routing". do `ip -route`, `man ip;man ip-route`. Any packet path that is not specified gets sent through the `default` route.

Search AskUbuntu for information on "bridging" (which I haven't tried, but might let you combine your interfaces).

Comment: I've added the information requested to the question, also I've never worked with it before. And I've searched on briding on AskUbuntu but I haven't found anything, but I'll keep looking.

Comment: Which commands should I use to setup the routes? An example would be great.

Comment: @mg20023: AskUbuntu is a Q&A site, not a conversation site. If you have a second question, ask a second question, don't bury your second question in a comment - consider future users trying to search the site. How could they find your second, buried, question?